# Convert date/time into timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to convert following date and time, into a timestamp 13 digits. Note I use strict mode.

**Date:**

Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

**Time:**
03:00

I tried to use Date.parse() but it was not working. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you want epoch timestamp ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the date object, add time as you wish and then use the [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function:

```js
"use strict";
var date = new Date('Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)');
date.setHours(parseInt('03'),[parseInt('00')]); //apply hours and minutes
console.log(date.toString());
console.log(date.getTime()); //use of getTime()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getTime` function:

```js
console.log(new Date('Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)').getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```js
console.log(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(+new Date("Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"))
```